# Call requires API level 14 (current min is 8): android.view.ViewGroup#canScrollHorizontally

Tags: android, viewgroup, android-version

I am getting this error:

> Call requires API level 14 (current min is 8):
>   android.view.ViewGroup#canScrollHorizontally.

How I can resolve this in API level before 14?

```
public class ViewPagerEx extends ViewGroup{
    @Override
    public boolean performAccessibilityAction(View host, int action, Bundle args) {
        if (super.performAccessibilityAction(host, action, args)) {
            return true;
        }
        switch (action) {
            case AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD: {
                if (canScrollHorizontally(1)) {
                    setCurrentItem(mCurItem + 1);
                    return true;
                }
            } return false;
            case AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_SCROLL_BACKWARD: {
                if (canScrollHorizontally(-1)) {
                    setCurrentItem(mCurItem - 1);
                    return true;
                }
            } return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            return false;
        }
        final int width = getClientWidth();
        final int scrollX = getScrollX();
        if (direction < 0) {
            return (scrollX > (int) (width * mFirstOffset));
        } else if (direction > 0) {
            return (scrollX < (int) (width * mLastOffset));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the support library: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#canScrollHorizontally(android.view.View, int)

Comment: it depends on you if you want to support more recent android phones you can increase your api level to 14...else you have to find another alternative to what you want to do,This is just a suggestion

Comment: it is not clear if you wrote a method called canScrollHorizotnally or you want to use the one provided by the framework

Answer (score 1):

go to `AndroidManifest.xml` you will find such code:

```
`<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />`
```

`android:minSdkVersion` is what your looking for, i means that your app will work on devises having the same API level.

`android:targetSdkVersion` is the API level that your app is designed to work on.

`android:maxSdkVersion` is the maximum API level your app can work on.

implies your app can work on devices between `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:maxSdkVersion`

so what you have to do is is changing you API level from 8 to 14 to support `android.view.ViewGroup#canScrollHorizontally.` since it was added in level 14 .

take into consideration that lowering  `android:minSdkVersion` will support more android devices but you wouldn't be able to use methods introduced in higher API levels .

for more info [check this detailed description](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

extra info :

1. kitkat  24.5% (API level 19)
2. JELLYBEAN  53.8% (API level 16,17,18)
3. ICECREAMSANDWICH  9.6% (API level 15 )
4. GINGERBREAD  11.4% (API level 10 )
5. FROYO  0.7% (API level 8 )

0.7% ??? you might think twice before setting `android:minSdkVersion="8"`

Comment: I think you are confusing targetSdkVersion with maxSdkVersion attribute.  You might want to check that link again :)

Comment: This answer is misleading. First, as noted, targetSdkVersion is _not_ the maximum API version that you app can run on. Second, lowering minSDK does _not_ make you lose functionality. You can _still code_ using them. What you will need to do, however, is take care of not calling said APIs on devices that do not have them. But it is wrong to say that _"you will loose advanced functionality added in higher API levels"_. That is wrong.

Comment: @Chilledrat exactly , how didn't i notice that , i will edit my answer . thanks :)

Comment: @david-cesarino first it was a misconception , i will edit my answer. second as you said :"take care of not calling said APIs on devices that do not have them" , i think its better to use the ` targetSdkVersion` rather than using a library or casting or any other means that can be used to avoid such error , since he cant control what the user may do . as for "you will loose advanced functionality added in higher API levels" i will correct it . am not that fluent at English so no worries , peole already understood what i mean :)

Comment: @HasanNahhal OK. I'm satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

From @KenWolf's suggestion: Using the [`support-v4`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#canScrollHorizontally(android.view.View)) library, you can use `ViewCompat` to check this:

```
// From within the View itself, just invoke the ViewCompat
// implementation with 'this' as the View parameter.
if (ViewCompat.canScrollHorizontally(this, 1)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:
Try changing your local method name to something else, and call it.
For example change it to canScrollHorizontallyLocal() and so where you are calling it. ViewGroup has a method named like that, and it might be trying the super method instead of yours.